# $M\times N$ Doesn’t Have a Module Structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

In Keith Conrad's [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) (page 4) is written:

> For two $R-$modules $M$ and $N$ , $M\oplus N$ and $M\times N$ are the
>   same sets, but $M\oplus N$ is an $R-$module and $M\times N$ doesn’t
>   have a module structure.

Out of context this phrase seems strange. I think of $\oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ and $\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ as a sets of collections $\{(m_i)_{i\in I}\}$ with term-wise operations (a difference only in case infinite $I$). Or as a universal objects in category of $R-$modules. In both cases $\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ is a module (as I think).

I get the impression that we **"make believe"** that $M\times N$ doesn’t have a module structure.

It seems to me that Keith Conrad considers $"\oplus"$ (and further $"\otimes"$) be a module (object of category $R-$mod), but $"\times"$ be only a set of variables for multi-linear functions. Why?

Further written:

> ... addition on $R$ is linear function $R\oplus R\to R$, but addition
>   on R is not a bilinear function $R\times R\to R$, as we saw above.
>   Multiplication as a function $R\times R\to R$ is bilinear, but as a
>   function $R\oplus R\to R$ it is not linear.

It strange question but why $"\oplus"$ has a natural addition and $"\times"$ has a natural multiplication?

Sorry for such vague questions, I hope you understand what confuses me.

Comment: The author is wrong, he means something else which is explained right afterwards. So just skip this sentence. If $M,N$ are modules and $|~|$ denotes the underlying set of a module, then a bilinear map is not a homomorphism on $M \times N$, but rather a (bilinear) map on $|M| \times |N|$. This is probably why he doesn't want $M \times N$ to be a module. But of course it is a module, with underlying set $|M \times N| = |M| \times |N|$. Never forget about forgetful functors! (Unfortunately this is done almost always)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Thank you Julian! In fact, I don't like the habit of giving answers in comments, but for some reason this is what I did here.

Answer (score 2):

The author is wrong, he means something else, which is explained right afterwards. I suggest just to skip this sentence. If $M,N$ are modules and $|-|$ denotes the underlying set of a module, then a bilinear map is not a homomorphism on $M \times N$, but rather a (bilinear) map on $|M| \times |N|$. This is probably why the author doesn't want $M \times N$ to be a module. But, of course, it is a module, with underlying set $|M \times N| = |M| \times |N|$. Never forget about forgetful functors!

[Converted my comment into an answer.]

Comment: My point was related to why we write bilinear functions as $B \colon M \times N \to P$ but you (usually) don't find people writing them as $B \colon M \oplus N \to P$. Sure, $M \times N$ could be given a module structure, which is exactly what $M \oplus N$ is meant to convey, but this is utterly *irrelevant* when working with a bilinear map on $M \times N$.  I updated the file to make the point clearer.